# Use find command with -perm and -maxdepth

Tags: linux, permissions, find

When I Enter this command:

```
$ find . -perm 777 -maxdepth 1
```

The following error occures:

`find: warning: you have specified the -maxdepth option after a non-option argument -perm, but options are not positional (-maxdepth affects tests specified before it as well as those specified after it).  Please specify options before other arguments.`

What does that mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The order of `find` arguments is very important, because they are evaluated as a boolean expression left-to-right with short circuiting:

```
# Deletes *.tmp files
find . -name '*.tmp' -delete

# Deletes ALL file, because -delete is performed before -name
find . -delete -name '*.tmp'
```

However, `-maxdepth` does not behave like this. `-maxdepth` is an option that changes how `find` works, so it applies the same no matter where it's placed:

```
# Deletes all '*.tmp' files, but only in the current dir, not subdirs
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.tmp' -delete  

# Deletes all '*.tmp' files, still only in the current dir
find . -name '*.tmp' -delete -maxdepth 1
```

Since you put the `-maxdepth 1` after a `-perm 777`, it looks like you are trying to make `-maxdepth` only apply to certain files. Since this is not possible, `find` prints this warning.

It suggests that you rewrite it into `find . -maxdepth 1 -perm 777` to make it clear that you intended `-maxdepth` to apply to everything.